# Upsert data into SQL Server from pyspark code

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark, sqoop

I have a pyspark dataframe that I wanted to upsert into a SQL Server table. I was looking at `df.write` modes and I do not see any upsert option. Therefore I am trying to write the dataframe into HDFS as parquet format and then sqoop the file using --update-mode allowinsert. However, I keep getting the following error:

> Got exception in update thread: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: One or more values is out of range of values for the datetime2 SQL Server data type

I tried to write the file as csv just to check if the contents/timestamp in the file is out of range, however the timestamps are correct.

Has anybody been able to write the pyspark dataframe into a SQL Server table?

Here's the function to write DF to HDFS:

```
def write_df_to_hdfs(df, filename, hdfs_location_working):
        """
        Function to write delta records dataframe to HDFS
        """
        logging.info("Started writing delta records dataframe to hdfs")
        df.write.save(hdfs_location_working, format='parquet', mode='append', timestampFormat='YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS',emptyValue="")
        logging.info("Successfully written delta records dataframe to hdfs")
```

Also, here's the sqoop command I m using to write that data into SQL Server:

```
sqoop export -Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=4096 -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx3000m -Dmapred.job.queuename=ici -Dsqoop.export.records.per.statement=30 -Dsqoop.export.statements.per.transaction=30 -libjars /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-7.1.6-1.cdh7.1.6.p6.12486751/lib/sqoop/lib/sqljdbc.jar --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://*******.hosts.cloud.ford.com;databaseName=SQTDIAPM_AM;schema=dbo;" \
--username 'user' \
--password 'pwd' \
--export-dir <HDFS Path> \
--table <tablename> \
--input-null-string '""' \
--input-null-string '\\N' \
--input-null-non-string '\\N' \
--update-key col1,col2 \
--update-mode allowinsert \
--batch \
-m 40 \
--verbose
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Post the code snippet that results in the error you posted?

Comment: The `CREATE TABLE` statement would also be useful to help debug this.